# Migrating Joomla 1.5 users to Wordpress 3.2

Tags: wordpress, joomla, migration

Is there an easy way to migrate Joomla 1.5 users to Wordpress 3.2? I've already successfully migrated most of the content using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/joomla-15-importer/) but need to migrate the users, too.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of.  I do know of some ways to get at it the other way (Wordpress to Joomla); however going the other way I think you'll be manually changing them over - but the passwords will have to be reset because of the encoding.

Comment: @Hanny how did you manage to convert Wordpress to Joomla passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [do these conversions](http://migratetowp.com/) at the database level. It's just a matter of mapping the fields in the two schemas and creating insert SQL sentences for WP based on the info in the Joomla database. However, it's true that the passwords cannot be migrated because of the different encoding system. You should just assign a fake password to each user and ask them to reset the password the first time they try to log in.